# Azure VM does not serve external website

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, azure-virtual-machine

- I spun up a Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter VM.
- Endpoints have ports 21,80,443 successfully added to the dashboard.
- Installed Wordpress/PHP on the VM using the Web Platform Installer.

Wordpress site works fine using localhost.

Trying to hit the DNS (*mysite*.cloudapp.net) or the public IP, shows just the generated version of the site below. Clicking links results in an "unable to connect" error.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when you finish installing wordpress, the address URL is set to 
`http:/localhost/wordpress`

When you browse your site with DNS, the resources file urls are still referring to like `http://localhost/......`

So, we need to sign in wordpress admin portal in your VM, click “setting”=>”general”, set “**WordPress Address (URL)**” and “**Site Address (URL)**” to `http://<your_vm_name>.cloudapp.net/wordpress`, and save changes.

If you have any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: This was it! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

wordpress is normally url based, make sure it's configured for wildcard or the cloudapp.net domain.

Answer (score 0):

So one thing you can do is see if you can log into `/WP-admin` and check the home and url links under `Settings>General` to see if they match site.cloudapp.net. If they do you might also want to check under your wordpress's theme files in `functions.php` and add the following lines to the top after `<?php`

```
update_option('siteurl','http://example.com');
update_option('home','http://example.com');
```